# autospecing not throwing exceptoin when invalid args are provided

Tags: python, mocking

Trying to mock a function return value, but using `Mock` causes it to not throw exceptions when invalid args are passed:

```
In [1]: from unittest.mock import MagicMock, Mock, create_autospec

In [2]: def f(a):
   ...:   return 1
   ...: 
   ...: mf = Mock('f', autospec=True, return_value=2)
   ...: mf(None)
Out[2]: 2

In [3]: mf() # Why no error here?
Out[3]: 2
```

When doing it with create_autospec, it does throw an exception:

```
In [4]: mf2 = create_autospec(f)

In [5]: mf2(None)
Out[5]: <MagicMock name='mock()' id='140657928683232'>

In [6]: mf2()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-377889015999> in <module>
----> 1 mf2()

<string> in f(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py in checksig(*args, **kwargs)
    177     func, sig = result
    178     def checksig(*args, **kwargs):
--> 179         sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
    180     _copy_func_details(func, checksig)
    181 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/inspect.py in bind(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3023         if the passed arguments can not be bound.
   3024         """
-> 3025         return self._bind(args, kwargs)
   3026 
   3027     def bind_partial(self, /, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/inspect.py in _bind(self, args, kwargs, partial)
   2938                             msg = 'missing a required argument: {arg!r}'
   2939                             msg = msg.format(arg=param.name)
-> 2940                             raise TypeError(msg) from None
   2941             else:
   2942                 # We have a positional argument to process

TypeError: missing a required argument: 'a'

In [7]:
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to create the `Mock` passing `spec=f` and not `spec='f'`. Otherwise you give a string as a spec, not the function `f`.

Second, mocks do not have the `autospec` argument. If you read all the [autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?#autospeccing) section of the documentation, you will notice that `autospec` is always mentioned in the context of using either [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) or [`patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object). These two have `autospec` in their signature.

This means that your `autospec`in the mock creation is accepted as part of the remaining `kwargs` that a mock accepts. These are used to configure additional attributes on the mock, at mock use time.

So while your mock is just using a normal `spec`, you can confirm that it accepts a read of an attribute that should otherwise not exist:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

def f(a,b):
    return 1
 
mf = Mock(spec=f, autospec=True, return_value=2)
print(mf)
print(mf(None))
print(mf())
print(mf.autospec)
```

Output:

```
<Mock spec='function' id='139874223464352'>
2
2
True
```

So if you write your code like below, autospec works:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def f(a):
    return 1

with patch("__main__.f", autospec=True, return_value=2) as mf:
    print(mf)
    print(mf(None))
    print(mf())
```

Output:

```
<function f at 0x7ff5a60a94c0>
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
... line 21, in <module>
    print(mf())
...
TypeError: missing a required argument: 'a'
```